# How do I update the dictionary of a mapped trait, after I've already constructed it?

Tags: python, traits, enthought, traitsui

I need to update the dictionary of a mapped trait some time after initial trait creation.
How do I do this?
The following code:

```py
from traits.api import (HasTraits, Trait)

class bar(HasTraits):
    zap = Trait("None", {"None": None})

    def __init__(self):
        # In reality, determined programmatically at runtime.
        add_dict_entries = {"One": 1}
        new_dict = {"None": None}
        new_dict.update(add_dict_entries)
        self.zap = Trait("None", new_dict)

theBar = bar()
```

yields:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tst_mapped_trait.py", line 13, in <module>
    theBar = bar()
  File "tst_mapped_trait.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.zap = Trait("None", new_dict)
  File "C:\Users\dbanas\Anaconda3\envs\pybert-dev\lib\site-packages\traits\trait_handlers.py", line 236, in error
    object, name, self.full_info(object, name, value), value
traits.trait_errors.TraitError: The 'zap' trait of a bar instance must be 'None', but a value of <traits.traits.CTrait object at 0x00000000034AA9E8> <class 'traits.traits.CTrait'> was specified.```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the following code worked:

```py
from traits.api import (HasTraits, Trait)

class bar(HasTraits):
    zap = Trait("None", {"None": None})

    def __init__(self):
        # In reality, determined programmatically at runtime.
        add_dict_entries = {"One": 1}
        new_dict = {"None": None}
        new_dict.update(add_dict_entries)
        # self.zap = Trait("None", new_dict)
        # self.zap.update(new_dict)
        # self.trait_setq(zap=Trait("None", new_dict))
        self.remove_trait("zap")
        self.add_trait("zap", Trait("None", new_dict))

theBar = bar()
```

**Note:** The commented out lines are things I tried, which did *not* work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're after, but I can make a few recommendations:

1. `Either` is a good choice here if you allow both `None` and `Dict`.
2. Use [dynamic initialization](https://docs.enthought.com/traits/traits_user_manual/advanced.html#dynamic-initialization) to create a value for a trait at runtime. It's preferred to using an `__init__` method.
3. If you really need an `__init__` method, you *must* call `super` inside of it for Traits to work properly, e.g. `super()**init**(*args, **kwargs)

Here's a version of your code that works and I think solves your problem.

```py
from traits.api import (HasTraits, Either, Dict)

class bar(HasTraits):
    zap = Either(None, Dict)

    def _zap_default(self):
        add_dict_entries = {"One": 1}
        new_dict = {"None": None}
        new_dict.update(add_dict_entries)
        return new_dict

theBar = bar()
print(theBar.zap)
```

And here's some feedback on the code that didn't work. The line `self.zap = Trait("None", new_dict)` below doesn't work because it tries to create a `Trait` object but `self.zap` only accepts `None` or `Dict`. My recommendation is to use trait definitions only for typing, at the class-level. Within methods, use regular Python types.

```py
from traits.api import (HasTraits, Trait)

class bar(HasTraits):
    zap = Trait("None", {"None": None})

    def __init__(self):
        # In reality, determined programmatically at runtime.
        add_dict_entries = {"One": 1}
        new_dict = {"None": None}
        new_dict.update(add_dict_entries)
        self.zap = Trait("None", new_dict)

theBar = bar()
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! In response to your numbered points:  

1. I don't want an `Either`, just a `Dict`.

2. Dynamic initialization still only allows me to define the trait contents once; I need to redefine the trait contents many times during program execution.

3. Yes, sorry, I should have included that in my example code, to be completely correct.

It's not clear to me how your proposed solution solves my problem, as I need to redefine the Trait's contents many times during program execution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's second attempt at an answer given the [original poster's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58050028/how-do-i-update-the-dictionary-of-a-mapped-trait-after-ive-already-constructed/58071547?noredirect=1#comment104135009_58071547)

If you want the type of `zap` to be `Dict` and only `Dict`, then define it as such. You can also inline the initial value if it doesn't have to be computer at runtime:

```py
>>> from traits.api import HasTraits, Dict
>>> class Bar(HasTraits):
...     zap = Dict({5: 'e'})
...
>>> bar = Bar()
>>> bar.zap
{5: 'e'}
```

If it needs to be computed at runtime, then use [dynamic initialization](https://docs.enthought.com/traits/traits_user_manual/advanced.html#dynamic-initialization) to initialize the value:

```py
>>> class Bar(HasTraits):
...     zap = Dict()
...
...     def _zap_default(self):
...         default = {}
...         default[1] = 'a'
...         return default
...
>>> bar_dynamic = Bar()
>>> bar_dynamic.zap
{1: 'a'}
```

Either way, the `zap` attribute on the `Bar` instance is a regular dictionary once the class has be instantiated (after `bar = Bar()`). You should use Trait types after instantiation, only regular Python objects. Traits is there to *define and enforce types*. The `type()` of the objects you're assigning to the typed traits (like `zap` here) are regular Python types.

Here's how you'd modify `zap` from outside of the class:

```py
>>> bar.zap[2] = 'b'
>>> bar.zap
{5: 'e', 2: 'b'}
>>>
>>> bar_dynamic.zap[3] = 'c'
>>> bar_dynamic.zap
{1: 'a', 3: 'c'}
```

And now from inside the class, as a regular attribute on `self`:

```py
>>> class Bar(HasTraits):
...     zap = Dict()
...
...     def _zap_default(self):
...         default = {}
...         default[1] = 'a'
...         return default
...
...     def add_pair(self, key, value):
...         self.zap[key] = value
...
>>> bar_method = Bar()
>>> bar_method.zap
{1: 'a'}
>>> bar_method.add_pair(26, 'z')
>>> bar_method.zap
{1: 'a', 26: 'z'}
```

Comment: Thanks for continuing to try and help me resolve this! I fear I have done a terrible job of clearly explaining what I want. So, I've tried again, from scratch: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59010527/how-do-i-make-an-edit-traits-gui-item-responsive-to-changes-in-its-dependencie