# How do I make an edit_traits() GUI item responsive to changes in its dependencies?

Tags: properties, enthought, traitsui

I'm designing a `HasTraits` subclass with *dependent* properties:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Example for SO question on dynamically changing Dict contents.
from traits.api   import HasTraits, Dict, Property, Trait, Int, cached_property
from traitsui.api import View, Item

class Foo(HasTraits):
    "Has dependent properties, which I'd like to remain up-to-date in the GUI."

    _dicts = [
        {"zero": 0, "one": 1},
        {"zero": 1, "one": 2},
        {"zero": 2, "one": 3},
    ]

    zap = Int(0)
    bar = Property(Trait, depends_on=["zap"])
    baz = Trait(list(_dicts[0])[0], _dicts[0])

    @cached_property
    def _get_bar(self):
        return Trait(list(self._dicts)[self.zap], self._dicts)

    traits_view = View(
        Item("zap"),
        Item("bar"),
        Item("baz"),
        width=500,
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Foo().configure_traits()
```

When I run this code I see:

[image: Initial GUI]

And if I change the value of `Zap`:

[image: After changing Zap]

Note the following:

1. After changing `Zap`, the address of `Bar` has changed.

   This means that changes to `Bar` are being dynamically updated in the GUI, while it's still opened; that's great! However...
2. The way `Bar` is displayed in the GUI is not very useful.

   I'd love to have `Bar` displayed as `Baz` is displayed: selectable by the user.

What I'd like is to have the best of both worlds:

- the dynamic GUI updating I see with `Bar`, and
- the display format of `Baz`.

Does anyone know how I can get this?

I've tried several ways of updating a `Baz`-like item dynamically, to no avail.
(See [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58050028/how-do-i-update-the-dictionary-of-a-mapped-trait-after-ive-already-constructed).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code gets me the behavior I want:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Example for SO question on dynamically changing Dict contents.
from traits.api   import HasTraits, Dict, Property, Trait, Int, cached_property, Enum, List
from traitsui.api import View, Item

class Foo(HasTraits):
    "Has dependent properties, which I'd like to remain up-to-date in the GUI."

    _dict = {
        "zero": 0,
        "one":  1,
        "two":  2,
    }

    _zaps = [
        ["zero", "one"],        
        ["one",  "two"],
        ["zero", "two"],
    ]
    zaps = List(_zaps[0])
    zap  = Enum([0,1,2])  # Selection of `zap` should limit the items of `_dict` available for selection.
    bar  = Enum(_zaps[0][0], values="zaps")
    bar_ = Int(_dict[_zaps[0][0]])

    def _zap_changed(self, new_value):
        self.zaps = self._zaps[new_value]
        self.bar_ = self._dict[self.bar]

    def _bar_changed(self, new_value):
        self.bar_ = self._dict[self.bar]

    traits_view = View(
        Item("zap"),
        Item("bar"),
        Item("bar_", style="readonly"),
        width=500,
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Foo().configure_traits()
```

Immediately after program start-up:

[image]

And after changing to `Zap` to '1':

[image]

Comment: I found this solution here: https://docs.enthought.com/traits/traits_user_manual/defining.html, at the end of the section just before the "Trait Metadata" section.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you wish both `bar` and `baz` to be `dict` type (in traits `Dict`). Actually, there are default display widgets for pre-defined trait types, which are more useful than showing address. I believe `traitsui` doesn't know how to properly display your custom Trait object unless you explicitly assign an editor for it. Note that for baz, although a dropdown menu is generated, it is only displaying the keys, which is not very useful either.

With that said, the following codes might meet your expectations.

```
class Foo(HasTraits):
    "Has dependent properties, which I'd like to remain up-to-date in the GUI."

    _dicts = [
        {"zero": 0, "one": 1},
        {"zero": 1, "one": 2},
        {"zero": 2, "one": 3},
    ]

    zap = Int(0)
    bar = Property(Dict, depends_on=["zap"])
    baz = Trait(list(_dicts[0])[0], _dicts[0])

    @cached_property
    def _get_bar(self):
        return self._dicts[self.zap]

    traits_view = View(
        Item("zap"),
        Item("bar", style="custom"),
        Item("baz"),
        width=500,
        )
```

Comment: This answer has the fundamental problem right:  There is no default viewer in TraitsUI for a generic `Trait` type.  You can get what you want by using a built-in Trait, as @BroCannon shows, or by writing your own class with a `default_traits_view`.